# Using threads without mutex.unlock in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm not sure why this code works:

```
m, n = Mutex.new, Mutex.new

t = Thread.new do
  m.lock
  p 'ha'
  sleep 1
  p 'ya'
  n.lock
end

s = Thread.new do
  m.lock
  p 'h'
  sleep 1
  p 'y'
  n.lock
end

t.join
s.join
```

I've avoided a deadlock by using the locks in the same order, but I'm not sure why this works since every mutex needs to have both mutex.lock and mutex.unlock, and this code doesn't have .unlock and still works. Why?

Comment: these threads would always run sequentially since the first thread does not unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs, [Mutex#lock](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Mutex.html#method-i-lock) waits until the lock is acquired. If you add some kind of output after acquiring the locks, you should see it's not executing in thread `s` until `t` is dead. When `t` is done and gets killed the lock is released.